# Parallel computations

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, parallelization

I'm having some problems with memory use and speed of a parallel computation. I've searched through the answers but only found allusions to the existence of a solution, but nothing concrete.

The problem is that I have a differential equation with a few parameters, and I want to calculate a single number from each solution and save that number to a table. (Also each time the boundary conditions change and I also need to perform some logic because the differential equation has points where it is numerically problematic.)

Currently I have the table, `T`, which I initialize with some values and use `SetSharedVariable`. Inside the `ParallelDo` I basically have something like `CalcT[parameters]` and `CalcT` sets up the boundary conditions, has some logic to identify if the numerical issues will show up and fix them, solve the differential equation, store what I need from the solution in T and then clear the solution.

The memory this notebook takes continues to grow as more iterations of the `ParallelDo` take place (several orders of magnitude more than `T` grows).

I've seen lots of answers saying

> don't use `SetSharedVariable`

but without actually suggesting an alternative.

Note: this wasn't a problem before using `ParallelDo`

Comment: "but without actually suggesting an alternative" Most answers saying this explain that the key is to make the parallel bits of computation independent of each other. Do not append to the same variable from multiple parallel threads. Use `ParallelTable`.

Comment: How do I use `ParallelTable` in this instance? Each loop here does a lot of operations and at the end produces one number I want to save in the table. If for nothing other than readability I can't put all of that in the ParallelTable (also not exactly sure how putting a bunch of logic inside a table entry works)

Comment: "Each loop here does a lot of operations and at the end produces one number I want to save in the table." That is precisely what `Table` is for. I do not understand what the problem is. Did you look at the `Table` documentation? Can you give a *very short* example of a task that you need to do and you think it cannot be accomplished with `ParallelTable`?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, I think. 

Instead of assigning `T[[whatever]] = thing` in `CalcT` and putting it in a ParallelDo

I should just have `CalcT=( STUFF; thing)` and have `T= ParallelTable[CalcT,{parameters, first values, final values, gaps}]`

Right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have implemented that but the memory usage is still growing a lot. The output of `CalcT` is `{thing,ClearAll[all of the temporary stuff]}[[1]]`. It is using 3GB more than when it started (it is still running, but that's expected) despite the table it is producing being, when full, only ~100MB. Does diagnosing this require a proper example?

Comment: Instead of using `ClearAll`, try using local variables in your function. Look up `Module`. The thing is that parallel calculations will use more memory than serial ones because each parallel kernel will have a copy of (at least some of) the data. It's hard to say more than this without a small example ...

Comment: I will try that. Though when I was looking earlier I saw lots of mentions of `Module` having memory leaks is this no longer an issue? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I don't think this will be an issue. It's easy to check by looking for symbols named as `name$123`. There's no guarantee that Module will help with memory usage, but it *will* make your code cleaner and easier to follow, which generally makes it easier to track down such problems. Just doing ClearAll is fragile and it can go wrong in many ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information you give, I understand that your calculations are memory intensive and each of the parallel computions is independent of the others and will take some time to finish. I have done things like this and here is a setup that has worked well for me:

- make sure your code is restartable: you better save your results to disk when they are done to avoid loosing all the effort which went into computing them in the case something goes wrong. If your code checks for availability of each result before it calculates it you can stop the calculation at any time and restart it which will cause it to only work on those results that are not available yet. As your results are simple, maybe a simple text file which you append to might do the job, a more sophisticated approach would be to write the results to some kind of database.
- The only really reliable way to avoid memory leaks for such long running mathematica jobs in my opinion is to run such computations in extra kernels and restart these after a given number of finished computations done in that kernel (or when the memory consumption of the extra kernel exceeds a given limit). As you are running your code in parallel you are already half there: You would need to make use of a loop, `ParallelSubmit`, `WaitNext`, `CloseKernels` and `LaunchKernels` to achieve this.

Here is some code which does the submit part and restarts each kernel that has finished an evaluation:

```
numkernels = 1;
CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[numkernels];
DistributeDefinitions[computeNumber];
knownresults = <||>;
evaluations = {};
AbsoluteTiming[
  Module[{res, e},
   Do[
     (* submit as many evaluations at a time as there are kernels available... *)
     While[Length@evaluations < numkernels,
       With[{c = c, b = b},
          AppendTo[evaluations,ParallelSubmit[{$KernelID, c, b, computeNumber[c, b, 10]}]]
        ]
      ];
      (* wait for next evaluation to finish and store the result *)
      {res, e, evaluations} = WaitNext[evaluations];
      Print["got: ", res];
      knownresults[res[[{2, 3}]]] = res[[4]];
      (* close and relaunch only the kernel that just finished it evaluation *)
      CloseKernels[res[[1]]];
      LaunchKernels[1];
      ,
     {c, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1},
     {b, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1}
   ];
   knownresults = Join[knownresults,Association[#[[{2, 3}]] -> #[[4]] & /@ WaitAll[evaluations]]]];
   knownresults
 ]
```

This expects a functions which computes something given two numeric parameters `b` and `c`, e.g.:

```
computeNumber[c_, b_, tend_] := Module[{sol},
   sol = First@NDSolveValue[
     {c*x'[t] == x[t], x[0] == b},
     {x}, {t, 0, tend}
   ];
   Pause[0.1];
   sol[tend]
]
```

Note that this is probably not as efficient as it could be but other constructs would make the code even more complicated. This approach really is only useful if any of the calculation takes at least a few seconds or minutes, in that case these inefficiencies are not really adding much to the total runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was super helpful :)

Comment: Having implemented this, I think, it seems mathematica is no longer fully utilizing the CPU, which it was with ParallelTable.

Perhaps I have implemented it incorrectly. It currently reads:

`Do[IDs={}; LaunchKernels[4]; Do[ 
AppendTo[IDs,ParallelSubmit[{parameters[[indices]]},Calculation]],{1000 calculations}];

Do[{data, junk, IDs} = WaitNext[IDs];T[[indices]]==data;,{the 1000 calculations];
CloseKernels[];,{indices}]`

Sorry for the mess Is there actually a problem with what I wrote?

Comment: I think what you wrote is not very efficient (AppendTo is known to be slow) and I also think you will abort all calculations whenever one calculation is finished which will cause the other jobs to be restarted. I also think that it is not efficient to submit all 1000 (or for the real problem even more) calculations at once. Of course doing this differently makes the code more complicated. You also have to take into account that you will only see benefits when a sigle calc. is sufficiently long...

Comment: I have added some example code to my answer. I hope that will be of help...

Comment: Thanks again :)

Comment: Sory, didn't edit in time and hadn't realised:

My issue really is more that there are a lot of calculations that, although quite fast, temporarily use a fair bit of memory. The other methods I've tried have a problem where the memory leaks eventually stop the thing being able to run. This approach fixes that but, doing it 1 by 1 like this leaves the kernels hanging around and makes it unacceptably slow (I need to do the calculations many times). Is there no way to let the parallel kernels do work more o the time and still, more occasionally, close and reopen them for memory reasons?

Comment: Yes, you can of course only restart every kernel when it has done a given amount of calculations. You would just have to add code which counts the finished calculations per kernel and the only do the `CloseKernels`-`LaunchKernels` part when the finished kernel exceeds that limit. As far as the "kernels hanging around" I don't understand. I don't see any unexpected Kernels on my machine...

Comment: Ah, by hanging around I mean, waiting to be given the next thing to execute, the output was almost always just flashing "Launching Kernel". I am seeming to get much better usage of my CPU (and speed in making my way through the computations) by writing something of the form: `results=Table[CloseKernels[];
LaunchKernels[4];ParallelTable[calculation[parameters],{some parameters}],{other parameters}]`

Comment: Yes, launching kernels is a relatively expensive action, so if a single calculation is short, you certainly don't want to restart after every evaluation. Your approach will of course also work, provided you find a separation of parameters which will work out fast and without memory consumption. If that is not the case, you would have to fall back to my suggestion...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Glad to know there isn't some reason that makes that a bad solution. It seems to me that you can always increase how many parameters are in "some parameters" if you are closing and launching too frequently and if not frequently enough you can always split a parameter which has a lot of values into several parameters with smaller ranges (say i-> j + 10k).

I suppose I should add something to the question then